# Getting exception ClassNotFoundException and don't know why

Tags: java, obfuscation, jwrapper

I have download, install the JWrapper and I have configure project Folder the root of the eclipse project.

[image]

After the build is finished! The project have jframe inside. I run the UnifiControllerAPI-windows64-offline.exe. And nothing happens. I open the log file and I see this exception:

```
 82985283 (+    3) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 82985283 (+    0)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 82985283 (+    0)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 82985283 (+    0)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 82985283 (+    0)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 82985283 (+    0)  at jwrapper.VMTransmuter.run(VMTransmuter.java:112)
 82985283 (+    0) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.package.main.TableWithExecutor
 82985283 (+    0)  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 82985283 (+    0)  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 82985283 (+    0)  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 82985283 (+    0)  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 82985283 (+    0)  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 82985283 (+    0)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 82985283 (+    0)  at jwrapper.JWrapper.main(JWrapper.java:372)
 82985283 (+    0)  ... 5 more
```

Comment: are you sure that **com.package.main.TableWithExecutor** is part of (in any referenced JAR-File) the classpath?

Comment: No, it isn't part! I have to make my project to jar and add it on the classpath, @Ben?

Comment: The class **com.package.main.TableWithExecutor** must be on the classpath. This class can be (of course) in any JAR, which is on the classpath. Your Projects-JAR doesn't seem to be on the classpath. So make it to JAR-File and add it to the classpath.

Comment: @Ben that was it!! Thanks, now it's working! Can you write your comment to as an answer, so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Projects-JAR doesn't seem to be on the classpath.
You have to make an JAR-File from your own Project (which contains the class **com.package.main.TableWithExecutor**).
After that, this new JAR-File must also be referenced by JWrapper.

Cheers!